# ¿Dónde está mi error en el código?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mysqli

estoy empezando a aprender sobre bases de datos y estoy trabajando con mysql, pero tengo un problema. Ya tengo una base de datos con una tabla y algo de información (estoy trabajando en local con phpmyadmin, pero no sé por qué no se me muestra la información que solicito a la base de datos, espero que me puedan ayudar y me digan dónde está mi error, además de corregirme. Gracias.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$bd_direccion = "localhost";
$bd_nombre = "prueba";
$bd_usuario = "root";
$bd_contrasena = "";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($bd_direccion, $bd_usuario, $bd_contrasena, $bd_nombre);
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM datos_personales";
$resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
$fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultados);

echo $fila[0];
echo $fila[1];
echo $fila[2];
echo $fila[3];


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que debería mostrar es la primera línea de una tabla que tengo en la base de datos, o sea un registro, pero el navegador está en blanco. No muestra ningún error, simplemente está en blanco.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta. Sé mas específico en tu problema, de lo contrario nadie va poder ayudarte. ¿Qué se supone que debe mostrar tu código? ¿Qué errores muestra?

Comment: ah ok, tienes razón

Comment: la direccion de la bd es localhost?

Comment: si, porque estoy trabajando en local

Comment: si ok.. pero seguro la direccion de conexion es localhost? y no otra cosa? que cosas probaste hasta ahora? php esta andando?

Comment: O sea, esto lo estoy haciendo por un tutorial que estoy viendo. Tengo el servidor corriendo y la página funciona porque antes la había probado imprimiendo cosas simplemente para ver si estaba todo bien. La verdad no he probado con nada más en la dirección de la base de datos.

Comment: Ahora le hice que me pusiera un mensaje de error si es que no realiza la conexión y efectivamente me manda el mensaje por lo que ni si quiera se logra establecer la conexión entre mi archivo php y la base de datos :(

Comment: Primero que todo prueba que tu conexion a base de datos es exitosa, por que puede ser que de hay salga tu problema

Comment: Eso es lo que pasa, ni siquiera se conecta de manera exitosa

Answer (score 0):

Tu unico problema es que dentro los parámetros de $fila[] tienes que poner los campos de la tabla creada en tu base de datos.
Haz algo parecido a esto, espero que aclare tu duda

//codigo

```
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$contraseña = "";
$baseDatos = "juegocartas";
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $contraseña, $baseDatos);

if (mysqli_connect_errno($conexion)) {
    echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}   

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios");
$fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
echo $fila['nombre'];
```

Comment: Amigo, es que estoy aprendiendo y el tutorial lo entendí perfecto, pero como dije antes ni siquiera me puedo conectar a la base de datos por lo que el problema está tal vez en la dirección como me dijeron antes o en alguna otra cosa.

Comment: Oh ya veo,bueno entonces primero verifica en tu XAMPP si estas conectado con apache y mySQL. Después verifica si el nombre de tu base de datos está bien escrita o si importaste bien la BD puede ser algo simple como eso.

Comment: No, lamentablemente no es nada de eso. Incluso lo hice con tu código y no pasa nada. Ya no sé qué hacer. :(

Comment: Creaste primero la base de datos algo parecido a esto y después la importaste: CREATE DATABASE juegoCartas
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;

USE juegoCartas;

CREATE TABLE usuarios(
 id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
 nombre VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
 email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
 fecha_registro DATETIME NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY(id)
);